# multi-tenant WCF howto

Tags: wcf, multi-tenant

im using the multitenant design from:
 http://romiller.com/2011/05/23/ef-4-1-multi-tenant-with-code-first/
and it works great :)

now i want to write a WCF Service to use this multitenant approach.
the thing is i would like to avoid writing code like

```
[operationcontract]
public List<Data> getDateById(string tenantShema, int id)
{}

 (EX: get data from Table.User1)
```

i would like the tenantScheme string to be background just like WCF authentication i guess.
witch i believe(not sure) gets sended in the header info of the xml and processed in the background.

is it possible and how ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

what type of security are you using ? do you users have roles ? if yes the role information will be available in service's security context, something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347790.aspx

Comment: id dont have any security yet, im waiting until i find the right approach for this problem.

Comment: id dont have any security yet, im waiting until i find the right approach for this problem.
maby i should clarify. the tenant string has little  to do with security  it does however instantiate my EF context to the right database Schema (EX:Table.User1). so i think the real problem is the stateless nature of a service.
right now im looking at statefull services with the [durableservice] attribute, it writes to a temp table row in sql i think.
problem is it all seems a little complex for doing something simple
and i need it to work on android and ipad as wel.